# contentEditable on react-select not making anything editable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

Unable to actually click on the selector and edit the text for selected value in react-select. I'm relatively sure it's not anything related to other settings in my react app, since I can make other elements editable, just this react-selector is giving me issues. Code is below...

```
function EditableSelect() {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

    const options = [
        { label: "Editable Options", value: 1 },
        { label: "Black Magic", value: 2 },
        { label: "Very Possible ", value: 3 }
    ];

    const onInputChange = (newValue, action) => {
        console.log("new value", newValue);
        console.log("action", action);
    };

  return (
        <>
            <Select
                defaultValue={selectedOption}
                onChange={setSelectedOption}
                isSearchable={true}
                options={options}
                contentEditable={true}
                onInputChange={onInputChange}
            />
        </>
    );
}
```

Searched StackOverflow and github for react-select and unable to find any similar issues and resolutions

Comment: can you explain what does "Unable to get contentEditable working" means? are you getting an error? have you tried to debug the issue? more information you can give, more we can help you

Comment: Just edited post, but essentially the selector cannot be clicked into and the text is uneditable. No bugs or warnings, just that the contentEditable functionality isn't working

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? As far as I can see, a react-select component doesn't have a property named `contentEditable`: https://react-select.com/props#select-props

Comment: I'm trying to enable a user to edit the label of the item that they've selected in the dropdown. Say we've got a list of ingredients and the user wants to rename the selected item from "Eggs" to "Organic Eggs'. In the React Select API, there is a contentEditable prop (https://react-select.com/props#select-props), which I thought would've given me the desired functionality, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I do know that React Select does have "Creatable" elements, but I don't want a user to create a new element when they interact and type in new text, just edit the pre-existing label!

Comment: @pls-help-me There's no `contentEditable` property for the `Select` component, only for the `Input` component.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I missed that. How do I format the input to be contentEditable, then? And would this allow me to get the desired functionality?

Comment: @pls-help-me have you tried `CreatableSelect` ?. It allows to create labels on the fly and we can add persistence

Comment: Ended up using MUI Autocomplete, seems to get most of the desired functionality